# How to debug Gala and other system apps?

Tags: development

I see [this other question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18216/setting-up-a-development-environment-for-elementaryos-apps) on a debug workflow for app development. In it, the answer is to use printfs and viewing the printed data on a terminal, but I don't see how that's easy with things like Gala, or settings plugs, etc.
How should I go about getting, say, Gala off the Github, building it, running it, and stepping through the code?

My background is embedded systems (PIC18), and writing the odd C# app in Visual Studio. With these, I can use an IDE to step through the code, set breakpoints, view variable contents, etc.